# Overriding a class from maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven-3

I have maven project which has dependency on another maven jar package.I have recreated a class which is already in maven jar with the same package and class name. When I receive the data from external resources, In my rest controller it is still pointing to old class which is presented in jar.

Shipment Details object overridden

[image]

Received data is populated with overridden object

[image]

Comment: Don't post code as pictures. Edit it as text into your question.

Comment: When you create a class with the same FQN as you have in an a jar, whichever will be used is depending on the classpath order. The first one will hide the seconds one, it is called "class shadowing". Relying on the classpath order is just asking for trouble. Can you not avoid this somehow eg. excluding the external jar, modifying the external jar?

Comment: Hi helospark,  There are some other classes Which I need to use it my project from that jar and class which I have redefined is needed for my customization. Could you please guide me to overcome this issue.

Regards,
Vamsi.

Comment: Right now in my web application I have jars one with my redefined class and one with old jar. Both jars contains class called ShipmentDetails with same class name and same package structure. When I receive the data from external source it was populating to old class.

Comment: Thank you @helpspark, I have changed the name of the jar which will help me to picked up the redefined class.